# incremental value for a column in python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a column `'value'` with `numerical values`. I have written a condition to create a column `'status'` to return `'G'` if value `less than '5'` else `'NG'`. But I want the output to be like `'expected output'`. If the condition is satisfied continuously it should be `incremented`. I have written the below code, but I'm not able to final tweak it.

```
h_count = 0
current = "G"

status = []

for i in range (len(df_2)):
    if df_2.iloc[i, 13] == 'NG':
        status.append("NG")
    elif  df_2.iloc[i, 13] == 'G':
        h_count += 0
        status.append(f"G{h_count}")
        if df_2.iloc[i+1, 13] == df_2.iloc[i, 13]:
            status.append(f"G{h_count}")
```

here `'13'` is the `column index`. How can I do this?

[image]

```
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [5, 5, 5,5,10,12,3,2,4,5,12,15,5,13,2],
        "Status": ['G','G','G','G','NG','NG','G','G','G','G','NG','NG','G','NG','G'],
        "Expected_Status": ['G0','G0','G0','G0','NG','NG','G1','G1','G1','G1','NG','NG','G2','NG','G3'],
    }
)
```

Comment: Could you please add the input and expected output, *as text*, to your question? That way, one can easily reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

1. You are not incrementing h_count. Use `h_count += 1` and move it after writing your first output to increment and begin with 'G0'.
2. In the elif statement, you can simply increment h_count if the current iloc value is 'G' **and** the next iloc is not G. You also have to check that the current iteration isn't larger than the length-1, to avoid accessing a row that doesn't exist (hence the `if i < len(df_2)-1`).

Fixing this with your code and reformatting to use your example data:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [5, 5, 5, 5,10,12,3,2,4,5,12,15,5,13,2],
        "Status": ['G','G','G','G','NG','NG','G','G','G','G','NG','NG','G','NG','G'],
        "Expected_Status": ['G0','G0','G0','G0','NG','NG','G1','G1','G1','G1','NG','NG','G2','NG','G3'],
    }
)
h_count = 0
current = "G"

status = []

for i in range(len(df_2)):
    if df_2.iloc[i, 1] == 'NG':
        status.append("NG")
    elif  df_2.iloc[i, 1] == 'G':
        status.append(f"G{h_count}")
        if i < len(df_2)-1 and df_2.iloc[i+1, 1] != df_2.iloc[i, 1]: 
            h_count += 1
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It definitely helps